# How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created new architecture my ERP application by asp.net core 2.0 with angular js 4.0.

Now I want to integrate crystal report my application.

I am searching to integrate crystal report my application, but can not find any solution.

How can I integrate that please tell me?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Am experiencing this now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Crystal Reports SDK works only with .NET Framework and Windows. The SAP hasn't released libraries for .NET Core and probably won't do it anymore.

I'm thinking about it too from long time. The only idea I have is to create a REST API service in ASP.NET Web Api to generate reports.

Comment: Official position a Crystal Reports for Visual Studio and .NET Core 5.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/13029137/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-and-net-core-5-a.html